# Jquery Datatable Colspan on Some Rows

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

Ok so I have a Jquery json call. It looks somewhat like this.

```
 $('#StockInvetoryReportList').dataTable({
        "filter": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("GetStockInventoryBalance", "Reports")",
        "aoColumns": [{ "mData": "Date"},
      { "mData": "Name" },
    { "mData": "Quantity" },
    { "mData": "isSummary" }
    ],   
            "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                aoData.push({ "name" : "StockNo", "value": $('#MaterialName').val() }),
                { "name": "ReportDate", "value": $('#ReportDate').val() };
            }
    });
```

And it generates this table:

```
+------------+---------+----------+------------+
|    Date    | Name    | Quantity | Is Summary |
+------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 10/01/2015 | Wire    | 500      | False      |
+------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 10/05/2015 | Wire    | 500      | False      |
+------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 10/15/2015 | Wire    | 600      | False      |
+------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 10/18/2015 | Wire    | 100      | False      |
+------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 10/19/2015 | Wire    | 200      | False      |
+------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 10/31/2015 | October | 1900     | True       |
+------------+---------+----------+------------+
```

I want to merge the first 2 columns if is summary is true. It should look like this.

```
+------------+------+----------+------------+
|    Date    | Name | Quantity | Is Summary |
+------------+------+----------+------------+
| 10/01/2015 | Wire | 500      | False      |
+------------+------+----------+------------+
| 10/05/2015 | Wire | 500      | False      |
+------------+------+----------+------------+
| 10/15/2015 | Wire | 600      | False      |
+------------+------+----------+------------+
| 10/18/2015 | Wire | 100      | False      |
+------------+------+----------+------------+
| 10/19/2015 | Wire | 200      | False      |
+------------+------+----------+------------+
| October           | 1900     | True       |
+-------------------+----------+------------+
```

And of course there would be more months in the list. Your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does the solution should use datatable function? Or it could be anything. Also a fiddle of the table would be great..

Comment: We are using datatable function all throughout our app and trying to be uniformed through all pages

Comment: can you give an example of the JSON?

Comment: What do you mean an expample of Json bro? Please see the json call. The value of the result is in the table.

Comment: @TheProvost, I mean the JSON - I do not want to reverse engineer it. My intent was to suggest an alternative solution - you cannot have real colspans in a dataTable body.

Comment: Oh do you mean the json array response? How can i get that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TheProvost. I've spent many hours to solve this problem, and I finally got it. I hope this will help.

Here is the answer of your problem:

```
var dgv_StockInvetoryReportList = $('#StockInvetoryReportList').dataTable({
        "filter": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bSort": false,
        "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("GetStockInventoryBalance", "Reports")",
        "aoColumns": [{ "mData": "Date", "mRender": function (data, type, full) { return dtConvFromJSON(data); } },
        { "mData": "Name" },
        { "mData": "Quantity" },
            { "mData": "isSummary" },
        ],
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "StockNo", "value": $('#MaterialName').val() });
            aoData.push({ "name": "ReportDate", "value": $('#ReportDate').val() });
        },

       //Here is the answer that I've created, 
       //All you have to do is to insert ID in every row that your datatable
       //created
      'fnCreatedRow': function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {   
           var cells = $('td', $(nRow));
           //I suggest you to make the word "TOTAL SUMMARY" instead of 
           //name of the month.. ^_^
           if ($(cells[1]).text().indexOf("//Insertthemonthhere") != -1) {
             $(nRow).attr('class', '//Name of the Class');
           }
       },
        //And here is where the cells span
       "drawCallback": function () {
             $("tbody").find("tr.total").each(function () {
                  var cells = $('td', this);
                  $(cells[1]).attr('colspan', 3); //adding span by 3
                  $(cells[2]).remove(); //remove the cell 
                  $(cells[0]).remove(); //remove the cell
             });

       }
});
```

I  hope it will works. -Cheers! ^_^

--KKK

Comment: Tnx!!! Saved me a day trying to figure this out :) Bounty cant be awarded yet though. Ill reward it as soon as its available